# SAS set into array values from table

Tags: arrays, variables, sas

Thanks user667489. Perhaps I think good.. But now I have problem with merge methods...

```
data Dictionary;
   input id_wiersz Labely $20. ;
   datalines;                      
1 Active
2 Gold
3 Prime
;

*Get the array parameter;
proc sql noprint;
select count(1) into :reccount from work.Dictionary ;
quit;

proc transpose data = Dictionary out = Dictionaryout;
    var Labely;
run;

data ArraryLoaded;
    set Dictionaryout (drop=_name_) nobs = nobs;
    array Dictionary _CHAR_;
    format col1-col3 $50.;
    retain col1-col3;
    array t[&reccount] $;
    do i = 1 to dim(t);
        if _N_ = 1 then t[i] = put(Dictionary[i], 8.);
            else t[i] = compress(t[i] || ',' || put(Dictionary[i], 8.));
    end;
    if _N_ = nobs;
    put "var1," t1;
    put "var2," t2;
    put "var3," t3;
run;

data Scinamy;
   input Description $20. ;
   datalines;                      
New old Active
New Active Old
ANother record
Records with Gold
Value with Gold
;
```

How to `lista(&reccount)` insert `array t[&reccount]`?

```
data Scinamy1;
  set Scinamy;
  array lista(&reccount) $8 _temporary_ ('Active','Gold','Prime');
  length AA $30 ;
  do i = 1 to dim(lista);
    if findw(Description,lista(i),,'spit') then AA=catx(' ',AA,lista(i));
  end;
  if missing(AA) then AA='Not Found';
  drop i;
run;
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hey Tom,
In step `"data ArraryLoaded"`'I loaded values to array from table.
And I need use this array to next step - `data Scinamy1;` - i want use array from `Data ArraryLoaded` instead `"array lista(&reccount) $8 _temporary_ ('Active','Gold','Prime');` from `data Scinamy1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the data from your small table to generate a temporary array in a future data step you could use the SAS macro processor to help you generate the statement.

If the list is small enough to fit into a single macro variable (64K characters) then you could use something like this:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select quote(trim(LabelY)) into :Label_list separated by ' '
  from work.dictionary;
%let no_labels=&sqlobs;
quit;

data new_step ;
   array lista(&no_labels) $20 _temporary_ (&label_list) ;
....
```

Watch out because `dictionary` is a special libref in PROC SQL. Prefixing with `work.` should make it work.  Or just name the dataset something else.

But it might just be easier to use the original dataset instead of an ARRAY.

```
data Scinamy1;
  set Scinamy;
  length AA $30 ;
  do i = 1 to nobs;
    set work.dictionary(keep=LabelY) point=i nobs=nobs;
    if findw(Description,LabelY,,'spit') then AA=catx(' ',AA,LabelY);
  end;
  if missing(AA) then AA='Not Found';
  drop LabelY ;
run;
```

Comment: Excellent! Both methods works great, and I understood two new methods processing :)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few options that you could explore:

1. Replace each distinct value of `Labely` with a different integer and [define a format to display the corresponding values](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/068-2007.pdf). Then you can use your existing `write_array` approach.
2. Define and populate a character array [within a data step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690506/reading-observations-from-sas-dataset-into-arrays) using a do-loop.
3. Use a [hash object](https://www.mwsug.org/proceedings/2014/RF/MWSUG-2014-RF12.pdf) to hold your dictionary instead of an array, and loop through it using a hash iterator.

Have a go at one of these and post another question if you get stuck.